# Wordpress's is_plugin_active_for_network function not working for multisites

Tags: plugins, multisite

I am in need to do some operation if user clicks on **Network Activate** button on my WP Plugin (in WP Multisite).

But I noticed that Wordpress's is_plugin_active_for_network function not working for multisites when I press the Network Activate button from the Main Administrator Panel.

It returns nothing, and hence the

```
if(is_plugin_active_for_network('abc/abc.php'))
```

is not fulfilled.

However when the Network is already Network Activated then the function - **is_plugin_active_for_network** is working fine (It returns **1** - i.e. **true**).

Can anyone please tell me how can I check whether the **Network Activate** button is clicked by the main administrator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that when you are activating the plugin. WordPress will send a Boolean flag to let your function know that this is a network wide activation.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate' );

function activate( $network_wide ) {

    // $network_wide will be TRUE if activation is network wide
    if ( $network_wide  ) {

        ... Do Stuff ...

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am using OOP approach in activating the plugin. $network_wide does not have any value all the times.